# how to create an object out of a seaborn plot for later reference

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

i'm trying to decide whether i should pursue a project involving a potentially large number of plots using matplotlib or using seaborn. the latter seems a lot more user friendly upon first examination so i am a bit biased that way. that said, i am unclear how i can create an object out of a plot that i can then call later. for example, suppose i have the following code:

```
x1 = np.random.randn(50)
y1 = np.random.randn(50)
data = pd.DataFrame ({})
data['x1'] = x1
data['y1'] = y1
sns.lmplot('x1', 'y1', data, fit_reg=True, ci = None)
```

this will display the plot as output in the iPython notebook. what i would like to do however is something like:

```
x = sns.lmplot('x1', 'y1', data, fit_reg=True, ci = None)
```

so that i can store x in a dictionary to be called later. this line runs (and will plot the output as well), but typing 'x' in a later cell displays nothing and just shows:

< seaborn.axisgrid.FacetGrid at ... >

any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: "Using matplotlib" and "using seaborn" are not alternatives. If you are using seaborn, you are using matplotlib.

Comment: sure. I meant the respective functions as alternatives to producing the same thing (a plot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Figure` object is accessible at the `FacetGrid.fig` attribute.